# Accessing __history object data in future method

Tags: apex, future

I have a future method inside which two methods are called

```
@future
public static void roundRobinAndMail(Id appId)
{
    RoundRobinAssignment(appId);
    NMEF_EmailUtility.sendEmailFromTemplate(appId);        
}
```

`RoundRobinAssignment()` actually insert/update data on a custom object called `Round_Robin_User_Group__c`. Field tracking is enabled in some of the fields in the custom objects.

So, When I insert/ update data in my object, I can assume that the `Round_Robin_User_Group__History` is updated and I want to do some calculations inside the 2nd method `NMEF_EmailUtility.sendEmailFromTemplate(appId);` with the __history object.

But, the fact is, I am not getting the expected value in the `__history` object.

What I see from the debugging is, the `__history` object is updating later and thus my 2nd method is not accessing the correct value in its runtime.

How to solve that ?

Comment: Does it work in non-future context?

Comment: I haven't tried that because it will hot SOQL 101 issue

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in **async** context.

As you can see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), commit to the database is one of the last operations in transaction (20th to be exact), and history objects are created AFTER the transaction ends. So you will not get them in any way in one transaction.

I recommend you to move update part to the **sync** context and leave the second part in **@future** method. Therefore, there will be 2 different transactions.

Comment: Thanks for your time. You are right. But, the problem here is, I can not move the update part in sync context as it will hit the SOQL 101 issue in that transaction. Looking for a way to call two asynchronous methods one after one.

Comment: In that case, I think, Queueable Apex is the rescuer.

Comment: @NoorAShuvo You are right, Queueable interface will suit you well.